# Clojure length of sequence

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I could have sworn I had `alength` working previously, but I don't quite know what I am doing wrong right now:

```
user=> (alength '(1 2 3))
IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: alength  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:79)
user=> (alength [1 2 3])
IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: alength  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:79)
user=> (doc alength)
-------------------------
clojure.core/alength
([array])
  Returns the length of the Java array. Works on arrays of all
  types.
nil
```

What should I be doing to get the length of a list/array in Clojure?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As the docstring says, `alength` works on Java™ arrays, such as a `String[]` or `Integer[]`, which is definitely an incompatible type with Clojure lists or vectors, for which you want to use [`count`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/count):

```
user=> (def x '(1 2 3))
#'user/x
user=> (def xa (to-array x))
#'user/xa
user=> (class x)
clojure.lang.PersistentList
user=> (class xa)
[Ljava.lang.Object;
user=> (alength xa)
3
user=> (alength x) 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method found: alength (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
user=> (count x)
3
```

`[Ljava.lang.Object;` is the weird way `toString` is [defined](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29) to output for native `Object` arrays.

Comment: Note, that `count` does also work for arrays. `alength` is only needed in speed-critical code where you already know that you have an array and need direct access. `count` would be slower here, because it's more generic.

Answer (score 52):

Try using [`count`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/count):

```
(count '(1 2 3))
=> 3
(count [1 2 3])
=> 3
```

Answer (score 14):

It should be [`count`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/count).

```
user=> (count '(1 2 3))
3
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be overkill, but you could imitate Common LISP's length function like this:

```
(def length 
 (fn [lst]
  (loop [i lst cnt 0]
   (cond (empty? i) cnt
     :t (recur (rest i)(inc cnt))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using the recursive way:

```
(defn length
 [list]
 (if (empty? list) 0
  (+ 1 (length (rest list)))))
```

Hope it helps!